# Issue transcode MPEG2 to DNxHD120

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, transcode, mpeg2

I use the software Kdenlive in Archlinux OS to transcode a 1 hour of video (1:12 :10) in Mpeg2 format in 1440x1080px 50i to DNxHD120 1920x1080 25p. Kdenlive print those parameters in the transcode's window : `-s 1920x1080 -r 25 -vb 120000k -threads 0 -vcodec dnxhd -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 %1.mov`.
The problem is : the final video is more shorter (00:53:35) and the video and audio is not synchronized. Do you know how resolve this issue?

Thank a lot :)

PeterPAN

Comment: Are you using ffmpeg directly, or via kdenlive?

Comment: No I use kdenlive, but I see the parametters and I can edit them.

Comment: I tried with DNxHD 50i but the result is same

Comment: AppleProres is same

Answer (score 0):

I success to resolve alone the problem : use the codec 'Remux MPEG2 PS/VOB' or those parameters from ffmpeg : '-vcodec copy -acodec copy %1.mpg'